# Is it RESTful if we fetch multiple resources using path variable over query parameter?

Tags: rest, api

Is it RESTful to have HTTP GET /employees/1,2,3,4,5? Or should this be modeled as HTTP GET /employees?id=1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 2):

This question is more about URI design than REST.

A URI is intended to identify a particular resource in the server. While `/employees` identify a *collection of employees*, a URI like `/employees/{id}` should identify an employee with the given id in that collection. The slash expresses [hierarchy](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.2.3).

If you want to get multiple resources from that collection (in fact, perform a [query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) in that collection), it makes more sense to use a *query parameter*. Both approaches are valid:

```
GET /employees?id=1,2,3,4,5
```

```
GET /employees?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4&id=5
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a simiar requirement to print all the data starting an index and ending with an index, I used query params as below. You can try this..
You can use..

../../employees?start=1&end=5

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getInjectResources(@QueryParam("start") String start, 
@QueryParam("end") String end){

    String queryParams = "start: "+start+" end: "+end;
    // Your logic here..
}
```

Comment: Why do you assume the OP is using Java and JAX-RS?